# Java Key Bindings

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I've got an assignment to do for uni and need to let a user control a game using the direction keys.

So far I've got the following, but this isn't working. Is there anything obvious that I'm missing?

```
    // key bindings

    // add the key bindings for up, down, left and right to the input map
    gamePanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN,0), "down");
    gamePanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP,0), "up");
    gamePanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT,0), "left");
    gamePanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT,0), "right");

    // assign actions to the key bindings in the action map
    gamePanel.getActionMap().put("down", new AbstractAction() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            move("DOWN");
        }
    });
    gamePanel.getActionMap().put("up", new AbstractAction() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            move("UP");
        }
    });
    gamePanel.getActionMap().put("left", new AbstractAction() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            move("LEFT");
        }
    });
    gamePanel.getActionMap().put("right", new AbstractAction() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            move("RIGHT");
        }
    });
```

Nothing is happening when pressing any of the directional buttons.

Thanks in advance for your help.

MCVE below- first one I've done so let me know if it's good enough or not

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.resources.windows;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MCVE extends JFrame
{
    // Game panel
    private JPanel gamePanel;

    private Container window;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        MCVE frame = new MCVE();

        frame.setSize(1000,700);

        frame.createGUI();

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createGUI()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        window = getContentPane();

        gamePanel = new JPanel();


        window.add(gamePanel);
    }

    private void keyBindings()
    {
        // key bindings

        // add the key bindings for up, down, left and right to the input map
        gamePanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN,0), "down");
        gamePanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP,0), "up");
        gamePanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT,0), "left");
        gamePanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT,0), "right");

        // assign actions to the key bindings in the action map
        gamePanel.getActionMap().put("down", new AbstractAction() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                System.out.println("down");
            }
        });
        gamePanel.getActionMap().put("up", new AbstractAction() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                System.out.println("up");
            }
        });
        gamePanel.getActionMap().put("left", new AbstractAction() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                System.out.println("left");
            }
        });
        gamePanel.getActionMap().put("right", new AbstractAction() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                System.out.println("right");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you debug? What does the `move(...)` method do? Have you debugged it? Where's your [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run and test?

Comment: the method works perfectly, as there are JButtons which also control the game and utilise the same method

Comment: .. So where's the MCVE?

Comment: I can only tell you one thing that I know with certainty : The error is not in the code you're posting. You must first either isolate your error and show it to us, or better, post for us your [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: For instance, please check out [my own mcve](http://pastebin.com/QdwjwmtN) that tests your code. It works. Up to you now to show the non-functioning code.

Comment: Hmm. Just creating an MCVE now, but this is literally copied directly from the code; if there's no error here I don't know where else it could be. One thing I've noticed is that there is a JTextField that is active when the code runs- I can click onto one of the buttons so that it's no longer active, but at this point the button is active (if that makes any sense whatsoever). Does the JPanel that has the key bindings need to be active instead? If so how would I go about doing that?

Comment: `"if there's no error here I don't know where else it could be"` -- that's what your MCVE and debugging are for -- to help you or *us* isolate your error.

Comment: Ha, good point! I've added an MCVE to my question. It's the first one I've so let me know whether or not it's good enough

Comment: You're runnable example never calls `keyBindings`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your runnable example never calls the `keyBindings` method, so they are never registered...

```
private void createGUI() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window = getContentPane();
    gamePanel = new JPanel();
    window.add(gamePanel);
    // This is going to help...
    keyBindings();
}
```

This is where debug statements and investing a small amount of time debugging your code will help.  When something doesn't work, always check that you've setup properly first...I still make this kind of mistake all the time ;)

And just in case, this example uses the `onKeyRelease` parameter to monitor press and release events as well as supports num-pad arrow keys

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel up;
        private JLabel down;
        private JLabel left;
        private JLabel right;

        public TestPane() {

            up = createLabel("UP");
            down = createLabel("DOWN");
            left = createLabel("LEFT");
            right = createLabel("RIGHT");

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            add(up, gbc);
            gbc.gridy = 2;
            add(down, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            add(left, gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 2;
            add(right, gbc);

            registerKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false), "up-press", new HighlightAction(up, true));
            registerKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_KP_UP, 0, false), "up-press", new HighlightAction(up, true));
            registerKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, false), "down-press", new HighlightAction(down, true));
            registerKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_KP_DOWN, 0, false), "down-press", new HighlightAction(down, true));
            registerKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false), "left-press", new HighlightAction(left, true));
            registerKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_KP_LEFT, 0, false), "left-press", new HighlightAction(left, true));
            registerKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), "right-press", new HighlightAction(right, true));
            registerKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_KP_RIGHT, 0, false), "right-press", new HighlightAction(right, true));

            registerKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, true), "up-release", new HighlightAction(up, false));
            registerKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_KP_UP, 0, true), "up-release", new HighlightAction(up, false));
            registerKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true), "down-release", new HighlightAction(down, false));
            registerKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_KP_DOWN, 0, true), "down-release", new HighlightAction(down, false));
            registerKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true), "left-release", new HighlightAction(left, false));
            registerKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_KP_LEFT, 0, true), "left-release", new HighlightAction(left, false));
            registerKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), "right-release", new HighlightAction(right, false));
            registerKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_KP_RIGHT, 0, true), "right-release", new HighlightAction(right, false));
        }

        public void registerKeyBinding(KeyStroke keyStroke, String name, Action action) {
            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            im.put(keyStroke, name);
            am.put(name, action);
        }

        public JLabel createLabel(String text) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
            label.setOpaque(true);
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            return label;
        }

        public class HighlightAction extends AbstractAction {

            private JLabel label;
            private boolean on;

            public HighlightAction(JLabel label, boolean on) {
                this.label = label;
                this.on = on;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (on) {
                    label.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    label.repaint();
                } else {
                    label.setBackground(null);
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Glad it helps, hope it's the actual problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

A JPanel has WHEN_FOCUSED key bindings defined for the left and right arrow keys. I have no idea what action is defined, but it’s not my action. That’s why I defined WHEN_FOCUSED key bindings as well as WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW key bindings for the arrow keys.

Here's my key bindings method.  You can ignore the WASD keys if you want.

```
    private void setKeyBindings() {
        InputMap inputMap = 
                gridPanel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W"), "up arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), "down arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "left arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"), "right arrow");

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "up arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "down arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "left arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "right arrow");

        inputMap = gridPanel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_FOCUSED);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "up arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "down arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "left arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "right arrow");


        gridPanel.getActionMap().put("up arrow", 
                new UpArrowAction(this, model));
        gridPanel.getActionMap().put("down arrow", 
                new DownArrowAction(this, model));
        gridPanel.getActionMap().put("left arrow", 
                new LeftArrowAction(this, model));
        gridPanel.getActionMap().put("right arrow", 
                new RightArrowAction(this, model));
    }
```

Comment: I just checked and find no previously registered key bindings on a `JPanel` at any FOCUS level

Comment: I wrote this method in March of 2014 with Java 7.  Perhaps the key bindings have changed  in Java 8?

Comment: Nope, tested using Java 8